# Is there a way to indicate an if-then statement based on a value range in a TrackBar? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, if-statement, range, trackbar

I am wanting to utilize a TrackBar in my Visual Studio project. My goal is to have the user scroll the TrackBar's indicator, and based on which value range it is in, it will change the a label's text.

Here's an example of how I tried to accomplish this:

```
Private Sub ScrollBarProgress() Handles MyBase.Load
        If SelfEvaluationReportBAR.Value = (0) Then
            FeelingLBL.Text = "Please select a value."
        End If
        If SelfEvaluationReportBAR.Value = (1, 25) Then
            FeelingLBL.Text = "I am starting to develop my ability to perform this task."
        End If
        If SelfEvaluationReportBAR.Value = (26, 50) Then
            FeelingLBL.Text = "I feel improvement in my ability to perform this task."
        End If
        If SelfEvaluationReportBAR.Value = (51, 75) Then
            FeelingLBL.Text = "My confidence in my ability to perform this task is substantial."
        End If
        If SelfEvaluationReportBAR.Value = (76, 100) Then
            FeelingLBL.Text = "I feel fully confident in my ability to efficiently and accurately perform the day to day tasks that are assigned to me."
        End If
    End Sub
```

The problem is that whenever I tried to set the range, it gives the following error:

> Error  BC30452 Operator '=' is not defined for types 'Integer' and '(Integer, Integer)'.

I think I have the formatting wrong. Does anyone have any ideas on how the range could/ should be formatted?

Here are my current settings for the TrackBar:

```
Private Sub SelfEvaluationReportBAR_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SelfEvaluationReportBAR.Minimum = 0
        SelfEvaluationReportBAR.Maximum = 100
        SelfEvaluationReportBAR.SmallChange = 1
        SelfEvaluationReportBAR.LargeChange = 5
        SelfEvaluationReportBAR.TickFrequency = 5
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: .Value returns an Integer, right? How could that be equal to a range?

Comment: @TheBlastOne Is there a way to make it equal to a range?

Comment: What's wrong with _>= AndAlso <=_ ?

Comment: @Steve I am new to VB.NET, I had no clue that was even an option.

Comment: No, but you can check if X is in Range Margin1, Margin2, ... and so on by checking if X is greater than the next limit. If X < Margin1 then ... elseIf X < Margin2 then ... and so on. Just make sure Margin1 < Margin2 and so on

Comment: @TheBlastOne Thank you, I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish your task

First

```
If SelfEvaluationReportBAR.Value >= 1 AndAlso SelfEvaluationReportBAR.Value <= 25) Then
    FeelingLBL.Text = "I am starting to develop my ability to perform this task."
End If
```

Second

```
Select case SelfEvaluationReportBAR.Value
   Case 0
      ....
   Case 1 To 25
      FeelingLBL.Text = "I am starting to develop my ability to perform this task."
   Case 26 To 50
      ...
   ' Other case follow
End Select
```

Third

```
If Enumerable.Range(1, 25).Contains(c) Then
    FeelingLBL.Text = "I am starting to develop my ability to perform this task."
End If
```

These are the ways that comes to mind, probably there are other.

The first two examples are the most basic approaches and with just five ranges I would stay with the simple If one. The third one is just to show how many ways exist but I don't really recommend to build an enumerable range only to check if a number is contained.

Comment: In order to make this code work the sub must be "Handles TrackBar.scroll